# How do I get a traditional url structure in a single page application (NO hash-bang)?

Tags: angularjs, url, routes, single-page-application

I want to build a single page application with angular.js the only thing is i want a traditional url structure.

Example:

```
  Before: www.example.com/#/index  
  After:  www.example.com/index  

  Before: www.example.com/#/user/21345678  
  After:  www.example.com/user/21345678
```

First of all is it possible?
Second how would i do that?
Any server except Apache XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable HTML5 mode within angular.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Then you also need to configure your sever. See this article: [Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

I'd suggest reading this short post: [Pretty URLs in Angular, Removing the Hashtag](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag). In it they also recommend setting `<base href="/">` within the head of your HTML.

Comment: So a little Google foo turns up the fact that it only works with webkit browsers (it dose fall back gracefully) but i would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same thing on a non webkit browser?

Comment: In my current project we're not using html5 mode. But when we were, I don't remember it being an issue getting it to work in FF. I prefer to use Chrome, but I do test in FF. I feel like this would've stood out to me. hmm